# Solving for two unknows on a system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have

$$\begin{cases}
c_1+c_2=1 \\
c_1(7/4)+c_2(5/4)=0  \\
\end{cases}$$
I want to find c1 and c2
to find **c1 I did this :**

the equation 1: c1+c2=1 I multiple the 5/4 cause I want to remove c2.

As a result I have for equation 1:  `5/4 c1+5/4 c2= 5/4`
and  I will remove the equation 2.

I have `(5/4 - 7/4)c1 +  (5/4 - 5/4)c2 = 5/4`

```
-2/4c1 + 0 = 5/4

c1 = -5/2
```

I find c1.

Now,I want to find c2.
From equation 1: c1+c2=1

I am doing this c2=-c1+1

c2=-5/2 + 1
c2=-5/2 +2/2 =-3/2

Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you went from
$$(5/4 - 7/4)c1 +  (5/4 - 5/4)c2 = 5/4$$
to
$$c1 + 0 = 5/4$$
you lost the factor in front of $c1$, which should be $-1/2$.  This gives
$$c1=-5/2$$
Once you have a proposed solution, you can substitute it into the original equations to see if it satisfies them.  If not, you have made an error somewhere.

Comment: I already edited - but that is correct the way I solve it or not?

Comment: Your approach is fine.  Did you plug your solution in?  Does it work?

Comment: IF i understand right you are asking if c1 + c2 = 1 .So I have -5/2 -3/2 which is -8/2 and that makes -4. Its wrong :/

Comment: You dropped the sign on $c1$ when you evaluated $-c1+1$.  Once your solution fails, you can work backwards to find the last equation it does not satisfy.  Your error is usually from there to the next one.